# Conditional Thymeleaf #aggregates.sum

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have a list of bill called bills and each bill has a status.
Actually I have the sum of bill.value, but I want just the sum of bills with a specific status.

My actual expression is: `${#aggregates.sum(store.bills.![value])}`

**Store.java**

```
@Entity(name = "STORE")
public class Store implements Serializable {
...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
  private Set<Bill> bills;
...
}
```

**Bill.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BILL")
public class Bill implements Serializable {
...
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status")
  private BillStatus status;
...
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Better to do it in the Service layer, not in the View

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) and [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) for this.  The expression would be:

```
${#aggregates.sum(store.bills.?[status=='STATUSHERE'].![value])}
```

Comment: I solved thsi problem in server side. That was a performace choice. But I think that your code solve the relacted problem